# Why does writing into temporary string stream object only print object addresses?

Tags: c++, c++98

The following snippet is simplified version of a logger that I use. It extends `std::ostringstream` and can be filled using the `<<`-operator. Upon destruction all content is written to `std::cout`.

Writing (`<<`) directly into a temporary object, `Logger()`, I would expect it to print that input, however, it only prints the address of something on `std::cout`. When writing into a reference of a temporary object, `Logger().stream()`, works as expected.

Why is that happening?

Btw, this behavior only occurs in C++98-land ([ideone](http://ideone.com/7RLSaf)), which I have to use. With C++11 ([coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c2af774bb958c44)) and C++14 ([ideone](http://ideone.com/cPgn4k)) both call variants work as expected. What's different in C++11/14?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class Logger : public std::ostringstream
{
public:
    ~Logger()
    {
        std::cout << this->str() << std::endl;
    }

    Logger& stream()
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    // 1.
    // Prints an address, e.g. 0x106e89d5c.
    Logger() << "foo";

    // 2.
    // Works as expected.
    Logger().stream() << "foo";

    // What is the difference between 1. and 2.?

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `operator<<` that handles insertion of `const char *` is a non-member template:

```
template< class Traits > 
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char,Traits>& os, const char* s);
```

It takes its stream by non-const (lvalue) reference, which does not bind to temporaries.

In C++98/03, the best viable function is the member `operator<<(const void *)`, which prints an address.

In C++11 and later, the library supplies a special `operator<<` for rvalue streams:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class T >
basic_ostream< CharT, Traits >& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&& os, 
                                            const T& value );
```

which does `os << value` and returns `os`, essentially performing the output operation on an lvalue stream.

Answer (score 11):

Relevant facts:

1. `Logger()` is an rvalue, but `Logger().stream()` is an lvalue.
2. The `operator<<` that takes a pointer and prints its address is a member of `ostream&`, whereas the `operator<<` that takes a `const char*` and prints the string is a free function,

   ```
   template<class traits>
   basic_ostream<char,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char,traits>& out,
   const char* s);
   ```

Note that the first argument is a non-const lvalue reference, so it can't bind to an rvalue. Therefore, if the stream is an rvalue, this overload isn't viable. Consequently the `const char*` is converted to `const void*` and its address is printed. When you use `Logger().stream()`, which is an lvalue, this overload wins and the string is printed.

In C++11, a new rvalue stream insertion operator is added:

```
template <class charT, class traits, class T>
basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>&& os, const T& x);
```

with the effect `os << x`. Now *this* overload wins in `Logger() << "foo"`, and forwards the argument as though the stream were an lvalue. Then the free function previously given is called.

Answer (score 5):

C++11 added this overloaded of [`non-member operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2):

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class T >    
basic_ostream< CharT, Traits >& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&& os,
                                            const T& value );
```

Now, the operator you think you're calling in the `Logger()` case is this one:

```
template< class Traits >
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,Traits>& os,  
                                        const char* s );
```

That works for the `Logger().stream()` case because that is an lvalue reference, but that doesn't work for `Logger() << "foo"` case. `Logger()` cannot bind to an lvalue reference. There, the only viable overload is the [*member* `operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt):

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( const void* value );
```

which prints the address.